# Запуск одной функции при загрузке и при клике JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! 
Как можно повесить два события на одну функцию? Нужно, чтобы она вызывалась при window.onload и при onclick. 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

объявите функцию вне "события", после чего привяжите её куда вам надо. Пример:

```js
function showAlert(){
  alert('Oh, well');
}

window.addEventListener('load', showAlert)
clickMe.addEventListener('click', showAlert)
// Или, если вам так угодно
document.querySelector('#clickMe').addEventListener('click', showAlert)
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">Click me!</button>
```